# MS Access VBA code to send an Outlook email

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, office365

I am trying to get Access to send a simple email programatically. I have added the Outlook 16.0 reference. Below is the code. When it gets to the With oMail part, it returns an error: "Application-defined of object-defined error."

It errors on the .ReplyRecipients.Add line. If I comment out that line, then it errors on the .Send line.

Note I am running the TestSend() sub to activate the SendEmailOutlook sub.

```
Sub TestSend()
    Call SendEmailOutlook("myemail@email.com", "Test message", "Test message.")
End Sub

Public Sub SendEmailOutlook(strTo As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String)
    
    On Error GoTo SendEmailOutlookErr
    
    Dim strEmail As String
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim oLook As Object
    Dim oMail As Object
    
    Set oLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oLook.createitem(0)
    With oMail
        .ReplyRecipients.Add "myemail@email.com"
        .to = strTo
        .htmlbody = strBody
        .Subject = strSubject
        .Send
    End With
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oLook = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    
SendEmailOutlookErrExit:
        Exit Sub
    
SendEmailOutlookErr:
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly, Err.Source & ":" & Err.Number
        Resume SendEmailOutlookErrExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out the line `.ReplyRecipients.Add "michael.thain@pnc.com"` and see if the error persists.

Comment: If I comment that out, it errors on the .Send line.

Comment: The line contains multiple calls, what method or property exactly gives the error?

Comment: Could be security related? I cannot replicate the issue on my machine - the email was issued. Change `.Send` to `.Display` to see if that works.

Comment: Also, the `Exit Sub` right after the `Set oLook = Nothing` is unnecessary. The sub will exit on the next line.

Comment: If I remove the ReplyRecipients line and I change .Send to .Display, then it works. But I plan to loop and send dozens of emails. I prefer not to have to manually click each one to send.

Comment: Do you have any problems with running the VBA code in Outlook, not external application? If not, than that is a security issue. See my post for more information.

Comment: I put the same code in a module in Outlook and when I run it, I get the same error. But you're probably right that it's a security issue, since it works when I change .Send to .Display. So maybe I will just have to click Send on each email manually. Not ideal but it will work.

Comment: Try to replace declarations to start using the early-binding technology first.

Answer (score 1):

In the code the late binding technology is used, so the COM reference is optional. But if you have already added the Outlook COM refence you may declare all Outlook objects instead of just having the object in the declaration. It can help. Read more about the late and early binding in the [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients) article.

Also the following line of code contains *multiple property and method calls*:

```
With oMail
  .ReplyRecipients.Add "myemail@email.com"
```

The code is valid. But it makes sense to declare each property or method on a separate line of code, so you could easily find the faulting one - where exactly the error occurs.

The [MailItem.ReplyRecipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.replyrecipients) property returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the reply recipient objects for the Outlook item. Use the `Add` method to create a new `Recipient` object and add it to the `Recipients` object. The `Type` property of a new Recipient object is set to the default for the associated `AppointmentItem`, `JournalItem`, `MailItem`, or `TaskItem` object and must be reset to indicate another recipient type.

```
Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add ("Jon Grande")  
myRecipient.Type = olCC
```

Another aspect is how Outlook has been configured to trust applications on a client computer, an application that uses the Outlook object model to access certain data or execute certain actions can invoke security warnings or throw errors when Outlook is automated without any UI. Depending on the type of information or action that the program was attempting to access or execute, there are three different security prompts that applications can invoke through the Object Model Guard: the address book warning, send message warning, and execute action warning. Read more about that in the [Outlook Object Model Security Warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/outlook-object-model-security-warnings) article.

Comment: I'll look at your links and see if I can make sense of it. I don't know what you mean by a COM reference.

Comment: > I have added the Outlook 16.0 reference.

Comment: Ok the early/late binding article is over my head but what I got from it is that I can use Dim oLook As Outlook.Application instead of Dim oLook As Object. I tried making this change but I get the same error.

Comment: You need to replace all declarations, not only for the `Application` object. Anyway, sounds like a security issue if you don't get any problems in Outlook VBA.